# Converting a byte file to an image in python

Tags: python, image, byte, python-imaging-library

So I have a byte file output by another program. That byte file contains a single frame of data from a camera output at 640x480 resolution. I want to read that file into python and convert it into an image.

I've been working with pil, but when I try to do this...

```
   def readimage(path):
      with open(path, "Ur") as f:
        return f.read()

   def main():
    bytes = readimage("color725.txt")
    image = Image.fromstring('RGB', (640,480), bytes)
    image.save("test.bmp")
```

I get an image that is not the image I'm starting with at all. (looks like nonsense)

When I try to do this...

```
def readimage(path):
    with open(path, "rb") as f:
        return bytearray(f.read())

def main():
    bytes = readimage("color725.txt")
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(bytes))
    image.save("test.bmp")
```

I get an error "IO Error: cannot identify image file". This isn't a problem with the file being there or not, because it's the image command that throws the error, not trying to open the file.

Those two attempts basically sum up what I've seen from documentation. Anything else I've seen hasn't exactly been applicable. Is there something simple I'm missing, or a better way somehow? Any help in finding an answer to the problem would be appreciated.

First few Lines of the byte file as hex:

1010 1100 1010 1100 1111 1000 1211 1000
1413 1000 1212 1100 1013 1100 0f11 1200
0f11 1200 0f10 1300 0f10 1200 0f10 1200
1013 1300 1011 1400 1014 1500 0f12 1600
0f15 1500 1115 1500 1315 1400 1211 1300
1110 1100 100e 0f00 0f0c 0e00 0f0d 0d00
0f0d 0c00 0e0c 0c00 0e0c 0b00 0d0c 0b00
0c0d 0d00 0e0f 0f00 1010 1100 0e0e 1300
0c0c 0f00 0d0b 0b00 0e0a 0900 0c0a 0800
0b0a 0900 0909 0b00 0808 0900 0707 0800

Comment: What format is the image in?

Comment: @kindall The image is a text file containing RGB information as bytes.

Comment: Is it numeric strings (e.g. "255" actually as the three characters "2", "5", and "5") or actual bytes?

Comment: @kindall Actual bytes, I'd almost rather it was just an integer text file. I'd know what to do with that.

Comment: If it's actual bytes of data, open the file in mode `"rb"` not `"Ur"`.

Comment: Just to be sure for file format, what is the size of your input file ?

Comment: @martineau Sorry, that needs edited. It was originally run with file mode 'rb' that's an error in my post here.

Comment: @SergeBallesta 1.34mb if it helps

Comment: Your file is too large, 640x480x3 is 921600 bytes exactly. There must be something about the file you don't understand yet.

Comment: Also, try using `Image.frombuffer()` instead of `Image.fromstring()`.

Comment: When you tried your first method (fromstring), was there anything resembling the real image? Dark images becoming dark images, some distorted but somehow recognisable features? IF you can, you could try to take a picture which is half white, half black and try your first method.

Comment: @MarkRansom So the byte array being written to the file is 1228800 bytes. So it's 640x480x4, which means its probably bgr32 and not rgb. Thank you for helping me to discover that. On the other hand. I'm still not sure where my additional filesize is coming from.

Comment: Could you show a hexa dump of the beginning of your file (say between 16 and 64 bytes) ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I added the first few lines of the text file as they appear in hex to the original post. Also my filesize was wrong. The file is 1.17mb which is not really surprising.

Comment: @SergeBallesta in the posted dump I see a zero in every fourth byte so I suspect you were correct, and there's no prefix either. jarrettHoltz what do you get when you try to decode the file with this new information? You can ignore the extra bytes on the file for now.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well honestly I don't know what to do with this information. Assuming the file is BGR32 as it seems to be, I've tried using the solution where the image mode is specified... But I just get an error telling me bgr is not a recognized mode. I've tried variations of 'BGR' also, but a quick google search isn't showing any bgr support in PIL either. None of the new information suggests a way to fix the other attempt though (at least not to me).

Comment: Try creating an image using slices for the source: `image = Image.fromstring('L', (640,480), bytes[0::4])` and see if that looks reasonable.

Comment: @MarkRansom, just fyi, `image = Image.fromstring('L', (640,480), bytes[0::4])` produces a grayscale image

Comment: @stoves that's correct - I was trying to get a single channel (either R or B depending on order) to verify that it wasn't garbage and validate some assumptions. The question is over a year old and apparently solved so it's a moot point now.

Answer (score 3):

So it appears that the image should be raw pivel values in a format that could be bgr32. But PIL only know to load images in RGB format. 
If that's true, you could try to do simple byte manipulation to convert your initial string to RGB

If byte order is really Blue, Green, Red, 0, you could try (starting from your initial code)

```
bytes = readimage("color725.txt")
RGBbytes = ''.join([ bytes[i+2:i+3] + bytes[i+1:i+2] + bytes[i:i+1]
                   for i in range(0, len(bytes) -1, 4)])
image = Image.fromstring('RGB', (640,480), RGBbytes)
```

re-ordering bytes to correct RGB order and removing the fourth one.

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you for this Serge, found myself working with similar images (bgr32 format) and your code for reorganizing the bytes and removing the alpha channel really helped

Comment: Any reason you used a slice notation and not just a single index, i.e. `bytes[i+2]` rather than `bytes[i+2:i+3]`?

Comment: @MarkRansom In Python2.x it would be the same. But with Python 3.x `bytes[i+2]` would be an int whereas `bytes[i+2:i+3]` is still a bytes object. As the question did not specify a version of Python I gave compatible code - BTW the name *bytes* is really bad :-(

Comment: Appears that `fromstring()` is no longer implemented, should be `frombytes()` now.